# A simple way to bind data revived through xml into a stack panel

Tags: xml, silverlight, data-binding, webclient, stackpanel

I am quite new to Silverlight, but I do have a grasp on it. My question is how to take the XML I have downloaded via Webclient, and place it into custom made controls? For example, the XML contains the data for the title, image, description, pubdate, etc, then in a canvas I put textblocks to hold the data from the XML. To further my question, how to you make copies of the canvas and place it into a stackpanel each containing its appropriate data? My xml is coded like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
  <UGR>
   <item>
      <title>Sample 1</title>
   </item>
   <item>
<title>Sample 2</title>
  </item>
   <item>
<title>Sample 3</title>
   </item>
  <item>
<title>Sample 4</title>
  </item>
```

As of this point in my .cs, I have

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WebClient UGRload = new WebClient();
    UGRload.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(UGRload_DownloadStringCompleted);
    UGRload.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("UGR.xml"));     
}    

private void UGRload_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    { 
      XDocument xmlSource = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var news = from ugrItem in xmlSource.Descendants("item")

                       select new NewsItemSetup
                       {
                           Title = (string)ugrItem.Element("title").Value,
                       };


            newsview.ItemsSource = news;
    }   
}
```

As for where i would like to put the data received from the xml, here is where i created the canvas.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
     <ListBox Canvas.Left="116" Canvas.Top="8" Height="464" x:Name="newsview" Width="518" Foreground="White">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5" Foreground="White"/>


                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Would the textblocks have to be data bound and then convert the entire canvas into a usercontrol in order to code in the xml data to the respective textblocks? Any help or advice would great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some type of ItemsControl to display each element in a bound collection. A ListBox (derived from ItemControl) seems to be a popular choice for stuff like this (I prefer just using a raw ItemsControl - but it depends on how ListBoxey my UI is). Define that "NewsItem" XAML inside the ItemsControl/ListBox's ItemTemplate.

For each collection element (your XML nodes) in the ItemsControl's bound ItemsSource property you'll get a fresh copy of the ItemTemplate's XAML. It will have it's DataContext set to the item in the collection - ready for binding. The items are arranged based on whatever Panel is defined for the ItemsControl (which is configurable).

Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data.aspx). (since you say you're new to SL, I recommend reading the whole series of blog post from the start)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to write up the code for it, but i have one question, when I run the application, it loads but then unloads, I checked all my code and all of them where spelled correctly, could it be a clash between the code? look at my post for the edit in what I put.

Comment: Hmm, you code looks find to me. Here's what I'd do to troubleshoot this: I'd remove the binding to Title temporarily. If that works you can add a converter to the binding to debug the binding. If it doesn't help, my guess is there's something with setting ItemSource. Maybe something with timing - you're setting ItemSource too soon or a threading issue with WebClient (but neither seem likely).

Comment: Sorry, was busy and haven't been able to work on the site. I removed the binding on Title, and the site loaded normally, but if I where to put normal text without binding, it also will crash the site, so what does this mean?

Comment: Strange!! (SL really needs better XAML error handling/debugging - hopefully in v5). I'll try to make a sample app with your code today if i have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would really appreciate and also be very grateful to learn from your sample, looking forward to it!